# How to replace words in an iframe in designMode?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, designmode

I want to replace some words like "php", because when I put PHP code in HTML tags the codes are hiding.

[image: Entered PHP code gets hidden when inside an HTML tag]

```
$('#editor').contents().find('<?php').replaceWith('');
```

or something like this:

```
$('#editor').contents().find('body').html().replace('<?php', '');
```

---

this is my code :

```
var myEditor = function(Tag){
        if (document.selection){
            var range = myIFrame.selection.createRange();
            range.pasteHTML("<" + Tag + ">" + range + "</" + Tag + ">");

        }else if(document.getSelection){
            var range = myIFrame.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var nnode = myIFrame.createElement(Tag);
                range.surroundContents(nnode);
                nnode.innerHTML = range;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code for how you add the HTML tag. Also note that instead of replacing the `<?php` you should rather replace the arrow brackets by their HTML entity representations `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: <!-- --> is a comment tag in HTML, that's why you're not seeing anything

Comment: i know that it's for <!-- --> but it appears automatically after i put the " <?php ".

Comment: F1 F1 F1...
no body ?